# Asp.net Hyperlink not working fine

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I have a asp.net hyperlink which im assigning the navigation url at run time. its working fine actually, but the problem is that, it doesn't show hand icon when mouse over. below is my script. Please what am i missing?

this code is added on the page load of the page. All i want is to see the hand icon on mouse over but its not showing..

```
    Link1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('/ViewFleetTerminal?Id=" + Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString() + "', 'window','HEIGHT=600,WIDTH=820,top=50,left=50,toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');return true");

    <asp:HyperLink ID="Link1" runat="server" Target="_blank">[Link1]</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: If you do a view source on the page in a browser, how does the link look?

Comment: Does the link have an `href` attribute?

Comment: Please reconsider your title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that your css isn't overriding the cursor. If you add a rule like

```
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

that should make your cursor into the hand when you hover over a link.

Comment: i dont want to use the href attribute coz of some reason. but thanks to brent i used ur method and its working fine. Thanks all for ur replied.

Answer (score 3):

It's because your link is 'dead'. According to the code you have posted it has no `href` value assigned. Anchor elements without a `href` have no `cursor: pointer` style applied.

Brent's answer is a workaround to this.

**Please also note:** There are many arguments *against* using anchor tags at all in this kind of scenario. It doesn't resemble an anchor tag in any way, it's merely an element with javascript events attached. I'm not going to give my opinion on this as I've not read up enough on the semantics of using a 'dead' anchor, but it's worth you researching it.